# Magento, Override local controller with other local controller

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to override local codepool extension controller with the other local extension, but its not working, don't know the reason, `firstextension` is the extension I want to override by `secondextension`

here is my code

`config.xml`

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <firstextension>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Secondextension before="Namespace_Firstextension">Namespace_Secondextension_Adminhtml</Namespace_Secondextension>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </firstextension>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

and `controller`

```
<?php

  require_once 'local/Namespace/Firstextension/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomController.php';
  class Namespace_Secondextension_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Namespace_Firstextension_Adminhtml_CustomController
  {
      public function saveAction()
      { 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please explain _not working_ have you tried a `die('in second module')` in `Namespace_Secondextension_Adminhtml_CustomController::saveAction()` ? What steps have you been taken to try to debug yet ? Because in the strict coding sense, there is nothing wrong with what you wrote.

Comment: yes I tried it, and by not working I mean secondextension is not overriding the controller of firstextension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by Changing

```
 require_once 'local/Namespace/Firstextension/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomController.php';
```

to

```
getModuleDir('controllers','Namespace_Firstextension').DS.'Adminhtml'.DS.'CustomController.php';
```

And also

```
 <Namespace_Secondextension before="Namespace_Firstextension">Namespace_Secondextension_Adminhtml</Namespace_Secondextension>
```

to

```
  <Namespace_Secondextension before="Namespace_Firstextension">Namespace_Secondextension</Namespace_Secondextension>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the typo in `Namespace_secondextension` which should stand `Namespace_Secondextension`, case sensitivity is important in Magento, is your problem?

Comment: Maybe, if that is not a problem to you, could you post the real namespace and module name plus class name and file path, that would maybe help us point to a solution.